# Correctness of public key cryptography

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Essentially, we have a value $n$ and an encryption exponent, $e$, is picked.

We then calculate the decryption exponent - the multiplicative inverse of $e$: $ed\bmod  φ(n)=1$

$\mathrm{Encrypt}(x)=x^e\bmod n$

$\mathrm{Decrypt}(x)=x^d\bmod n$

$\mathrm{Decrypt}(\mathrm{Encrypt}(x))=(x^e\bmod n)^d\bmod n=x^{ed}\bmod n$

So far this makes sense, however, the text I'm looking at jumps to $x^{ed}\bmod n=x$ which confuses me.

I understand $ed\bmod  φ(n)=1$, but I'm confused how the exponent dissapears.

---

I've noticed $\forall a:\exists t: a^t  \bmod n=a\bmod n$ and suspect this has something to do with it.

Comment: $ed$ should be congruent to 1 mod $\phi(n)$, not mod $n$.

Comment: @MatthewTowers right

Comment: Both of your comments helped me figure this out

Comment: Actually, no. @Moo those slides show how ed vanishes when modding with p or q, not when modding with $n$

Comment: by the Chinese remainder theorem, if $p$ and $q$ are (relatively) prime and $x^{ed}\equiv x \bmod p$ and $x^{ed}\equiv x \bmod q$, then $x^{ed}\equiv x \bmod pq$